# select count only showing 1 result and the wrong one

Tags: mysql

I want to search TABLE1 and count which `number_id` has the most 5's in `experience` column.

TABLE1

```
+-------------+------------+
| number_id   | experience |
+-------------+------------+
|  20         |  5         |
|  20         |  5         |
|  19         |  1         |
|  18         |  2         |
|  15         |  3         |
|  13         |  1         |
|  10         |  5         |
+-------------+------------+
```

So in this case it would be `number_id=20`

Then do an inner join on TABLE2 and map the `number` that matches the `number_id` in TABLE1.

TABLE2

```
+-------------+------------+
| id          | number     |
+-------------+------------+
|  20         |  000000000 |
|  29         |  012345678 |
|  19         |  123456789 |
|  18         |  223456789 |
|  15         |  345678910 |
|  13         |  123457898 |
|  10         |  545678910 |
+-------------+------------+
```

So the result would be:

```
000000000 (2 results of 5)
545678910 (1 result of 5)
```

So far I  have:

```
SELECT number, experience, number_id, COUNT(*) AS SUM FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.number_id = TABLE2.id
WHERE experience = '5' order by SUM LIMIT 10
```

But it's returning just

```
545678910
```

How can I get it to return both results and by order of number of instances of 5 in the experience column?

Thanks

Comment: You should tag your questions with `mysql` as well as/instead of `mysqli`, they will get seen by more people. I've done it for you for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the results that you want. The subquery fetches all the `number_id` that have `experience` values of 5. The `SUM(experience=5)` works because MySQL uses a value of `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`. The results of the subquery are then joined to table2 to give the `number` field. Finally the results are ordered by the number of `experience=5`:

```
SELECT t2.number, t1.num_fives
FROM (SELECT number_id, SUM(experience = 5) AS num_fives
      FROM table1
      WHERE experience = 5
      GROUP BY number_id) t1
JOIN table2 t2
ON t2.id = t1.number_id
ORDER BY num_fives DESC
```

Output:

```
number      num_fives
000000000   2
545678910   1
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d707ac/5)

Answer (score 1):

Add a group by clause:

```
SELECT number, experience, number_id, COUNT(*) AS SUM
FROM TABLE1
JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.number_id = TABLE2.id
WHERE experience = '5'
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3 -- <<< Added this clause
ORDER BY SUM
LIMIT 10
```